# How do I stop the "Index" and "Python Module Index" from appearing using sphinx autodoc?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

I'm using sphinx autodoc for retrieving class and module docstrings.

When I use autodoc sphinx automatically generates an ugly page called `Python Module Index`.

I can only disable this page if I add `:noindex:` to every single `autoclass` and `automodule`.

**Question:**
Is there a way to globally insert `:noindex` into these ReStructured Text directives?

---

My `index.rst` for reference:

```
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 5
   :glob:

   README
   CHANGELOG
   DEV-README
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to remove this under index.rst. See if there is a line:

```
* :ref:`modindex`
```

Comment: The Module Index isn't appearing anymore. I think it was a caching issue with :ref:`modindex` in `docs/_build/doctrees` from a separate sphinx project.